# DeflateStream CopyTo MemoryStream

Tags: c#, memorystream, deflate

Tyring to compress and decompress `MemoryStream` but it seems that `CopyTo` does not work like it's expected? Why? How to fix this?

```
public static MemoryStream Compress(MemoryStream originalStream)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Original before compressing size: {0}", originalStream.Length.ToString());
    MemoryStream compressedMemoryStream = new MemoryStream();

    using (DeflateStream deflateStream = new DeflateStream(compressedMemoryStream, CompressionMode.Compress, true))
    {
        originalStream.CopyTo(deflateStream);
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Compressed size: {0}", compressedMemoryStream.Length.ToString());
    return compressedMemoryStream;
}

public static void Decompress(MemoryStream compressedStream)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Compressed before decompressing size: {0}", compressedStream.Length.ToString());
    using (MemoryStream decompressedFileStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
         using (DeflateStream decompressionStream = new DeflateStream(compressedStream, CompressionMode.Decompress, true))
         {
              decompressionStream.CopyTo(decompressedFileStream);
         }
         Console.WriteLine("Decompressed size: {0}", decompressedFileStream.Length.ToString());
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Original before compressing size: 5184054
Compressed size: 0
Compressed before decompressing size: 0
Decompressed size: 0
```

Comment: Make sure your originalStream is at `Position = 0` before you started copying from it. Otherwise it won't find anything to copy, being at the end of the stream (since you wrote data to it before?).

Comment: @RayKoopa, yes you are right! Post answer i will accept it!

Comment: @A191919 and remember to move the new `MemoryStream compressedMemoryStream` to `Position = 0` at the end

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`CopyTo` starts copying bytes from the *current position* of the source stream.

Since you posted the resulting compressed stream size being 0, I'm pretty sure that `originalStream` is positioned at the end of the stream, so no bytes were copied / compressed.

Ensure the position is `0` so it can find any data to copy and compress to your stream.

As @xanatos mentioned, the same applies to `Decompress`, so ensure that `compressedStream` is positioned at 0 too before decompressing it.